# Can't disable password prompt for ssh

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I try to disable password login for a user using ssh. Here's my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file

```
# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
PasswordAuthentication no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

UsePAM no
```

I believe these three directives are needed to make the change, however, after I reload, it doesn't make a difference.

I am pretty sure I edited the `sshd_config` file, **not** `ssh_config` file.

Any idea why?

Comment: Possibly one of those cases where you're changing options that require an actual restart and a reload is insufficient?

Comment: I did try stop and start sshd, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you restarted sshd after making the configuration change to /etc/sshd_config, you should be fine. Although it will NOT authenticate passwords after this configuration is set, it will continue to prompt for passwords to the best of my knowledge.

I would restart ssh, then test using a known working password. You should be able to observe that entering the correct password results in a warning telling you incorrect password.

I personally haven't seen any ssh prompt without a password, even when set only to use keys.

Hope this helps, best of luck

Answer (score 0):

Have you added support for keys?  Shared keys have been around for awhile.  [This webpage is from ye olde days of 2001](http://www.paulkeck.com/ssh/) and it's still relevant today.  Add the following settings:

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

Without those two, you won't get support for logging in with shared keys.  If the first page isn't nice enough for you, [here's one from 2008](http://hocuspokus.net/2008/01/ssh-shared-key-setup-ssh-logins-without-passwords/) that should work all the same.

After changing /etc/ssh/sshd_config (or whatever directory/file combination it is in your installation), you will need to restart the *sshd* server.  Shared keys also require that you install them for the account you are logging in with; no key = no login with shared keys.  Using a 2nd ssh session, attempt to log in with your shared key.  **Don't close your first shell (the one you used to make the edit to sshd_config) until you have it working 100% right.**